# Se puede crear un trigger en SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

Buenas quiero crear un trigger que cuando yo cree un Procedure el trigger tome el nombre del procedure y el nombre de la base data usada y este se inserte con los 2 nombres data base usada y nombre de procedure en una tablade X basedato ¿es posible esto? Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROC_INSERTADOS

DECLARE
@Proc_Name varchar (max),
@DataBase_Name varchar (max)

SET  @Proc_Name = (SELECT proc FROM inserted)
SET  @DataBase_Name = (SELECT proc FROM inserted)

INSERT registro_procedure (Proc_Name,DataBase_Name,FECHA)
VALUES
(@Proc_Name,@DataBase_Name,GETDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, todos los datos son almacenados en la base master y en una vista la cual puedes consultar.

```
select * from master.information_schema.routines
```